# Next JS with API routes vs. Express.js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, next.js

How does NextJS with API routes differ technically from running an Node.js server with Express.js?

For example - If I want to develop a full-stack web application with MongoDB, can I use only Next.js with API routes for that purpose? Is connecting and modifying the database safe from the API routes, or is it a security risk?

In other words, are the Next.js API routes exposed into the client browser where the end user would be able to modify the code?

Comment: _"are the Next.js API routes exposed into the client browser"_ - No, they're not. I'd recommend a read through [API Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nextjs API routes are ran serverside. Per the docs,

> They are server-side only bundles and won't increase your client-side bundle size

So the end user is unable to modify the code. Just make sure they are in the /pages/api folder. Read the docs for more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

Comment: They run depending on how you deploy the app. It is incorrect to assume that they can only run serverless.